# Creating a split-button-dropdown in asp.net MVC with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a [split button dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split) using Bootstrap and ASP.NET MVC 5, but I cannot seem to render the correct markup. This is what I have so far...

```
<div class="btn-group">
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ClientTypeID }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" })
        <a class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ClientTypeID })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ClientTypeID })</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

I have no doubt that this is my own fault, but can anybody please point out what I should actually have in my template. Instead of the required drop down, I am seeing the initial "Details" button, and I am seeing the drop down caret, but clicking on the caret does not show the additional items.

In case it makes a difference, I am using the default templates from VS2013 along with the [Cosmo theme from Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/cosmo/). This is also being rendered in a table cell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure you have registered jQuery before bootstrap.min.js.
- Debug the error using Developer Tools available in all modern browsers.
- Chrome use Ctrl+J, IE use F12, FireFox use Shift+F2

Happy Coding..

Comment: On the flip side, I could actually include them! The default project template did not actually work correctly when mixing WebForms and MVC so neither were actually being included. All working just great now. Fiddler pointed that out to me!